# Updating table using looping cursors

Tags: sql-server-2008

To assist in understanding I have a table like this:

```
itemcode itemname icode serialnum
1        A        10    0
2        B        10    0
3        C        10    0
4        D        11    0
5        E        13    0
6        F        20    0
7        G        20    0
```

I want the result to look like the table below using a single update query with the help of looping cursors:

```
itemcode itemname icode serialnum
1        A        10    1
2        B        10    2
3        C        10    3
4        D        11    1
5        E        13    1
6        F        20    1
7        G        20    2
```

Item code is the primary key in this table. The logic behind generating the serial number is whenever icode changes the serial number gets reset to 1. I need a single update query to update the table with the help of cursors if someone can assist with a solution?

Comment: i tried but it was not working... now its working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a sequential serial number for every icode-group. Then you can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY icode`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT itemcode, itemname, icode, serialnum,
     ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY icode ORDER BY itemcode) AS RN
  FROM dbo.TableName 
)
UPDATE CTE SET serialnum = RN;
```

If you want it to be reculculated on every update you could use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TableName_Updated
ON dbo.TableName 
FOR UPDATE /* Fire this trigger when one or multiple rows are UPDATEd */
AS BEGIN
    WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT itemcode, itemname, icode, serialnum,
         ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY icode ORDER BY itemcode) AS RN
      FROM dbo.TableName t INNER JOIN INSERTED i 
        ON t.itemcode = i.itemcode
    )
    UPDATE CTE SET serialnum = RN
END
```

Comment: Hi can you get me the same results using Cursor!!! :) Logic behind calculation of Serial Number is when Item_Icode changes the serial num gets reseted to 1

Comment: `itemcode` should never change(without excuse) since it's the primary key.

Comment: yeah Itemcode will never change as i made it as a primary key but Item_Icode can Change :)

Comment: @user1823200: With `Item_Icode` you mean `icode`? Then you just have to put above sql in a stored-procedure and call it whenever you want. You could even put it in a trigger(although i wouldn't recommend).

Comment: @user1823200: Updated my answer with a trigger approach.

Comment: Trigger approach too is Gud :) Thanks tim once again. But i have to complete this task with the help of cursors :(

Comment: @user1823200: Cursors are slow and should be avoided if possible. Set operations are always much more efficient. From [SQL-Team](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/cursors-an-overview): _"Please note that cursors are the SLOWEST way to access data inside SQL Server. They should only be used when you truly need to access one row at a time. The only reason I can think of for that is to call a stored procedure on each row.  In the Cursor Performance article I discovered that cursors are over thirty times slower than set based alternatives."_ http://www.sqlteam.com/article/cursors-an-overview

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed64f/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Item
(
  itemcode int,
  itemname char(1),
  icode int,
  serialnum int
)

insert into Item values
(1, 'A', 10, 0),
(2, 'B', 20, 0),
(3, 'C', 11, 0),
(4, 'D', 10, 0),
(5, 'E', 20, 0),
(6, 'F', 10, 0),
(7, 'G', 13, 0)
```

**Query 1**:

```
update I
set serialnum = rn
from
  (
    select serialnum,
           row_number() over(partition by icode order by itemcode) as rn
    from Item
  ) I

select *
from Item
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed64f/1/0)**:

```
| ITEMCODE | ITEMNAME | ICODE | SERIALNUM |
-------------------------------------------
|        1 |        A |    10 |         1 |
|        2 |        B |    20 |         1 |
|        3 |        C |    11 |         1 |
|        4 |        D |    10 |         2 |
|        5 |        E |    20 |         2 |
|        6 |        F |    10 |         3 |
|        7 |        G |    13 |         1 |
```

## Update

A version that uses a cursor instead of not using a cursor.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed64f/2/0)

```
declare @itemcode int
declare @rn int

declare ItemCursor cursor local static forward_only read_only for 
select itemcode,
       row_number() over(partition by icode order by itemcode) as rn
from Item

open ItemCursor

fetch next from ItemCursor
into @itemcode, @rn

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  update Item
  set serialnum = @rn
  where itemcode = @itemcode

  fetch next from ItemCursor
  into @itemcode, @rn
end

close ItemCursor
deallocate ItemCursor
```

Comment: what  is I in the Query is it a table name? and what is from Item, Is it Itemname

Comment: @user1823200 `I` is an alias for the sub query. The only table here is `Item`. Replace `Item` with whatever your table is called.

Comment: Hi can you get the same results using Cursor!!! :) Logic behind calculation of Serial Number is when Item_Icode changes the serial num gets reseted to 1

Comment: @user1823200 Please update your question with sample data and expected result that shows what you mean. The solution using row_number is working for what you have showed so far.

Comment: @user1823200 Have you??? There is no difference in sample data or expected output.

Comment: Yeah there is no difference between sample data or expected data when the icode is 10,10,10 the serial num is 1,2,3 and when the icode changes the serial num gets reset to 1. eg- say in the above table icode is 10 the serial num generated is 1 and when icode is 20 the serial num generated is 1 it got reset.

Comment: @user1823200 Then I suggest that you use `row_number` to update your table. It is way better than using a cursor.

Comment: hmmm yeah row_number is gud away of simplying the above task? :) but i was assigned a task with the help of cursors :(

Comment: @user1823200 Ok, so this is for some educational assignment with the purpose of learning how to use cursors?

Comment: Nope in the Company they have assigned this task for me :) i am newly joined as junior software developer.. yeah its for purpose of learning as well as getting brushed up before the project starts :)

Comment: @user1823200 I think you should go to your manager and tell him/her that you now know better than to use cursor for this task. In almost all circumstances cursors can be avoided and also probably should be avoided.

Comment: @user1823200 I have added a version that uses a cursor.